# Remote installation of Mountain Lion OS X 10.8 as an upgrade, not a fresh install

Tags: macos, upgrade, install

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions (or know if its even possible) to remote upgrade a fleet of Macs from 10.6.8 to 10.8 remotely. I presume I can push the installESD through ARD, but I want it to run completely unattended.

If it is not possible through "traditional" methods does anyone know of any tools that might help automate this process?

Thank you for your thoughts, feedback, and suggestions.

Comment: I don't know much about mass deployment tools, but [this Cult of Mac article](http://www.cultofmac.com/180549/how-to-deploy-mountain-lion-in-business-and-education-the-right-way-feature/) might be useful to you.